# Grid-like labels-stickers dynamically generating Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, npm, label

So I have a bunch of json, infinite amounts the case being there are reports being generated on a daily-basis, I have to generate a PDF with all the necessary information
one label after the other, side by side, grid style.

The only npm library that seems to solve my need is [react-avery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-avery) which on first sight looks like the perfect solution to my problem, since I'm using Avery labels and my Front-end is react based so I could just get the json from my backend and generate the pdf, the but is that this library hasn't been maintained for 3 years and the documentation doesn't make anything clear for me on how to use it, giving me a bunch of errors when I try to implement it.

Any idea or package for me to achieve this ? Front-end focused or Back-end with Node.js would do.

I have tried pdfkit and I'm currently using it for pdf generation but when It comes to placing the items side by side it doesn't do the trick.

[labelmake](https://github.com/hand-dot/labelmake) and its successor [pdfme](https://github.com/pdfme/pdfme) seem to offer me the functionality of creating and adding the placeholders for the templates, but I can't find anything about the grid functionality I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdfme to create your own grid by placing a text object at each label location (calculated by dividing up the A4 page by the number of label rows & cols):

```
const fontSize: number = 12;
const labelWidth: number = 99;
const labelHeight: number = 38;
const sheetHeight: number = 297;
const sheetWidth: number = 210;
const sheetCols: number = 2;
const sheetRows: number = 7;

const template: Template = {
  basePdf: BLANK_PDF,
  schemas: [
    {
      0: {
        type: "text",
        position: { x: (sheetHeight / sheetRows) * 0, y: (sheetWidth / sheetCols) * 0 },
        width: labelWidth,
        height: labelHeight,
        alignment: "center",
        fontSize: fontSize,
      },
      13: {
        type: "text",
        position: { x: (sheetHeight / sheetRows) * 6, y: (sheetWidth / sheetCols) * 1 },
        width: labelWidth,
        height: labelHeight,
        alignment: "center",
        fontSize: fontSize,
      },


const inputs = [{ 0: "a", 13: "z" }];

generate({ template, inputs }).then((pdf) => {
console.log(pdf);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could design your labels using HTML and CSS, then use paged.js to render that out to a PDF. Paged.js is a javascript library that implements the W3C Paged Media standards, which allow you to design for print using HTML and CSS. Paged.js works both as a polyfill in a browser and as a command line interface that generates PDFs.

The polyfill version is great for easy design iteration of label sheets in a browser and then the command line version can then be used to generate PDFs in production.